How to click on scroll bar and move up or down one page at a time
Ubuntu 24.04, Gnome 48,
All the proposed solutions that I have seen have come to nothing, solutions from 2 years ago, 1 year ago, don't work anymore. I never imagined it could be so hard to achieve.
I have entered the text found below in both Home/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css and Home/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=false
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
But no joy. Obvs.

what are you trying to scroll?

It seems to behave the same on everything but firefox browser is the most problematic for me

What are the results of cd /home/$USER/.config/gtk-3.0 && ls ?

It also behaves like that in Files so not strictly a firefox or browser issue.

@Karel: bookmarks  gtk.css  settings.ini

"I have entered the following text in Home/.config/gtk-3.0" is incorrect. What file did you edit? Is it  gtk.css settings.ini ? Please comment or edit your question.

It's actually both files (gtk.css and settings.ini) that have "gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=false" although settings.ini has it also as "gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false" (note the spaces) i.e. two versions of the text in settings.ini IDK which syntax is correct, just copying solutions from other peoples similar questions.

Nobody knows...

Should I put this text in gtk-4.0 ?

@karel so what attracted you to this question ? Do you have an answer to the problem ?

@Johnh I missed your edits so I wasn't aware that you had answered the question from my previous comment and that this question is clear enough now.

But no solution ?
